# Get substring between two last instances of character in url

Tags: javascript

I have urls which look like this :`http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/BR0Y3MZ21bo/0.jpg`. Can someone help me extract the "ID" `BR0Y3MZ21bo` between the last two slashes in the url?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [split()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp), split will give you array of string being separated by `/` and your desired string is at second last index of array.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SVjDn/)**

```
arr = url.split('/');
arr[arr.length-2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var url = 'http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/BR0Y3MZ21bo/0.jpg'; // window.location.href;
 var page = url.substr(0, url.lastIndexOf('/')); // output -> http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/BR0Y3MZ21bo
 var str = page.substr(page.lastIndexOf('/')+1); // output -> BR0Y3MZ21bo
 alert(str); // BR0Y3MZ21bo
```

#### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tMeaW/1/)